# FlurrySDK with cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate FlurrySDK framework in my app using Cocoapods (as I'm doing with already a lot of framework) but for some reason xcode keeps throwing this compilation error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've added this line in my Podfile :

```
pod 'FlurrySDK'
```

and I ran a pod update wich successfully updated my Pods project (I can see FlurrySDK in my pods).

My AppDelegate.m is as follow :

```
#import <FlurrySDK/Flurry.h>
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [Flurry startSession:FLURRY_API_KEY];
    ...
}
@end
```

I'm really desperate here, I'd like to keep my dependencies where they belong but it's seems that FlurrySDK podspec is not working properly...

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with your build architectures or the compatibility between their framework and armv7.

Comment: I built this in a fresh project and it installed and linked correctly. You may want to make sure your gem is up to date. `[sudo] gem update`

Comment: @KeithSmiley, I tried the gem update and then a pod update but no changes. It's really weird cause the autocompletion works for the import and even for the SDK methods, but as soon as I launch compilation, still the same error...

Comment: Also my project is set to accept armv7 and armv7s.

Comment: I'm currently linking FlurrySDK to my main project without issue, but I'd really like to be able to link it through cocoapods. I'll have a look at the podspec later to try and solve this issue.

Comment: Could you post the full linker command XCode issues? The Flurry SDK from the podspec appears to have that symbol for armv7. Does it work for the simulator?

Comment: Are you opening the workspace file instead of the project?

Comment: Yes I'm opening the workspace. You can also see this issue here :https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/844

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out where the issue was, it was linked to a faulty podspec file from a library I was using.
The podspec did not pose any problem while making a `pod update` although the line specifying the libraries was corrupted. I changed :

```
 s.framework    = 'CoreLocation, MapKit'
```

to

```
 s.framework    = 'CoreLocation', 'MapKit'
```

(note the single quotes: was one string, edited to be a list of two strings) and everything is now back on track.

Comment: Which podspec file is this in?

Comment: It was in one of my own podspec made on a project I forked (SVGeocoder), but I stopped using it.